# Method isn't available in unit test

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs

I created new project in VueJS with TypeScript.

My component with methods to test:

```
<template>
    <div></div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component
export default class Slider extends Vue {
  private slide: number = 0;
  private sliding: boolean = false;

  public setSlide(slide: number): void {
    this.slide = slide;
  }

  public setSliding(sliding: boolean): void {
    this.sliding = sliding;
  }

  private onSliderStart(slide: any): void {
    this.setSliding(true);
  }

  private onSlideEnd(slide: any): void {
    this.setSliding(false);
  }
}
</script>
```

Test:

```
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils';
import Slider from '@/components/Header.vue';

describe('Slider', () => {
  const wrapper = shallowMount(Slider);

  it('check Slider is a Vue Instance', () => {
    expect(wrapper.isVueInstance()).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('setSlide is func', () => {
    expect(typeof wrapper.vm.setSlide).toBe('function')
  })
});
```

and now I would like do test but methods setSlide, setSliding isn't available in wrapper :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you have to cast `wrapper.vm` as `any` for TypeScript not to complain:

```js
it('setSlide is func', () => {
  expect(typeof (wrapper.vm as any).setSlide).toBe('function')
})
```

Or at the top of your tests:

```js
const wrapper: any = shallowMount(Slider);
```

Source: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-test-utils/issues/255#issuecomment-433312728.

Comment: It's not working because I received undefined. I havn't any method or variable in wrapper.vm :(

Comment: I copy-pasted your code and it's working fine for me. Are you sure you're importing `Slider` from the right place, `Header.vue`?

Comment: You are the best! I should change file from Header.vue to Slider.vue

Comment: By casting to any you throw away type safety. Why use typescript then? This is hack, not solution.

Comment: This IS a solution, even if you think it's a hacky one. Just because TS need an `any` at one place doesn't take away it's importance in the rest of the project.

Comment: @chipit24 Nothing to do with the rest of the project. It just defeats the point of using TS. It  IS a hacky solution until Vue provide a fix. That is not to say this is a bad answer, just there is no other solution currently.

Comment: The ```const wrapper: any = shallowMount(MyComponents); ``` works for me

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```js
import YourComponentHere from "@/components/YourComponentHere";
import { shallowMount, Wrapper } from "@vue/test-utils";

describe("test", () => {
  const wrapper: Wrapper<YourComponentHere & { [key: string]: any }>;
  it("does something", () => {
    expect(wrapper.vm.someThingWhatever).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

The advantage here is that you don't need to cast `wrapper.vm` to `any` everytime you use `wrapper.vm`

Comment: You can also try Wrapper<Vue & {[key:string]: any}> as I've had some weird errors with this lately

Comment: I'm confused.  Why doesn't `Wrapper<YourComponentHere>` come with all the types needed?

Comment: Somewhere in you project you have a line 'declare module *.vue' that sets all vue imports so that they have the Vue type (generic with no type info, no prop names and their interfaces etc.). There is currently no mainstream way to do what you're asking. You asked why: it's supposedly hard to retrieve prop etc. information from a .vue SFC file - that's all I know

Comment: Interesting.  But if I say `class MyComponent extends Vue`, then declare members on there, you're saying those types don't affect the type of the class?

Comment: They do. You can write `type a = My Component['yourPropName]'` at the top of the script block and type is going to work fine. It's just that information is lost when you are outside the file where your component is defined, due to the 'declare module *.vue line' which basically means 'assume all .vue default imports are of type Vue (generic typeless interface)'

Comment: So if those types are available, why squash them in other files?